# How can I avoid spaces when collapsing a character vector?

Tags: r

I have a character vector and want an output like this:

```
"(WLNXL0427M)|(QWDAF7505E)|(ZTKQC4319H)|(RUQAI0874B)|(BAUPR0486O)"
```

I use

```
v <- c("WLNXL0427M", "QWDAF7505E", "ZTKQC4319H", "RUQAI0874B", "BAUPR0486O")
a <- paste("(", v, collapse = "|", ")")
a
```

And get

```
"( WLNXL0427M )|( QWDAF7505E )|( ZTKQC4319H )|( RUQAI0874B )|( BAUPR0486O )"
```

How can I avoid the spaces?

Comment: set `sep = ''` inside the `paste` function.

Comment: Okay--probably I'd have figured this out immediately myself if I had read `?paste` more accurately. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also `paste0()` could be used i.e.

```
v <- c("WLNXL0427M", "QWDAF7505E", "ZTKQC4319H", "RUQAI0874B", "BAUPR0486O")
a <- paste0("(", v, collapse = "|", ")")
a
```